# How to get the default gmail username and password

Tags: android, passwords, gmail, default

Now I am doing a android project. The project needs to get the default username and password of Android phone.

I don't know how to get the default gmail information of one Android Cell Phone. Can u help me. Thanks.

Comment: Getting the gmail password... you are dreaming !

Answer (score 3):

You should read about [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to login using the gmail user but you will not get the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
        String possibleEmail = account.name;
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this requires the GET_ACCOUNTS permission: